# Purrr Prop.table in R

Tags: r, data.table, tidyverse, purrr

I use this to get frequency table of all column. However, I want to convert same thing to frequency percentage table then to a dataframe

```
mtcars %>% map(table) %>% do.call(rbind,.)
```

My try

```
mtcars %>% map(prop.table(table))
```

It gives an error, please help

> Error in sum(x) : invalid 'type' (closure) of argument

## Edited

Here is the output which I get once I run the code sent by you, its runs perfect
https://m.imgur.com/gallery/lFcKTVo

I just have a doubt that I had few categorical column in my dataset, example gender which can be seen in image URL. Can I build a function where I mention my categorical variable & get same thing as for each category & total if possible

I tried doing something like this

```
temp <- split(df1, df1$gender) 
temp %>% 
  imap(~ .x %>% 
         table() %>% 
         prop.table() %>% 
         as_tibble() %>% 
         set_names("value", .y)) %>% 
  reduce(full_join) %>% 
  arrange(as.numeric(value)) %>% 
  base::t() %>% 
  as_tibble(rownames = "-") %>% 
  set_names(unlist(.[1,])) %>% 
  slice(-1)
```

I get below error
Error in table(.) : attempt to make a table with >= 2^31 elements

Dput of dataframe working on

```
structure(list(company = c("Sports Authority", "Sports Authority", 
"Sports Authority", "Sports Authority", "Sports Authority", "Sports Authority", 
"Sports Authority", "Sports Authority", "Sports Authority", "Sports Authority", 
"Sports Authority", "Sports Authority", "Sports Authority", "Sports Authority", 
"Sports Authority", "Sports Authority", "Sports Authority", "Sports Authority", 
"Sports Authority", "Sports Authority", "Sports Authority", "Sports Authority", 
"Sports Authority", "Sports Authority", "Sports Authority", "Sports Authority", 
"Sports Authority", "Sports Authority", "Sports Authority", "Sports Authority", 
"Sports Authority", "Sports Authority", "Sports Authority", "Sports Authority", 
"Sports Authority", "Sports Authority", "Sports Authority", "Sports Authority", 
"Sports Authority", "Sports Authority", "Sports Authority", "Sports Authority", 
"Sports Authority", "Sports Authority", "Sports Authority", "Sports Authority", 
"Sports Authority", "Sports Authority", "Sports Authority", "Sports Authority", 
"Sports Authority", "Sports Authority"), variety_products = c(6, 
6, 7, 7, 3, 3, 5, 8, 8, 8, 7, 9, 5, 8, 8, 1, 9, 6, 8, 5, 9, 10, 
4, 3, 7, 8, 9, 7, 7, 6, 9, 7, 8, 8, 6, 6, 4, 9, 9, 8, 9, 5, 8, 
4, 7, 8, 4, 7, 8, 4, 8, 6), quality_products = c(10, 8, 9, 10, 
6, 4, 8, 8, 10, 8, 7, 8, 6, 10, 9, 10, 10, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, 
7, 6, 8, 8, 10, 10, 7, 3, 9, 6, 8, 8, 3, 10, 8, 10, 10, 8, 9, 
7, 9, 7, 8, 8, 6, 7, 10, 8, 9, 9), brand_products = c(10, 7, 
8, 10, 7, 5, 7, 7, 10, 8, 6, 7, 6, 8, 8, 10, 8, 7, 9, 10, 7, 
10, 7, 7, 8, 8, 10, 10, 7, 6, 9, 8, 9, 9, 6, 8, 9, 10, 7.96078431372549, 
6, 10, 6, 9, 10, 8, 7, 5, 6, 8, 7, 10, 8), overall_product_satisfaction = c(9, 
7, 9, 10, 5, 3, 8, 8, 10, 8, 7, 8, 6, 10, 9, 10, 9, 8, 9, 10, 
8, 10, 7, 6, 7, 8, 8, 10, 8, 3, 9, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 7, 10, 8, 7, 
9, 7, 9, 7, 7, 8, 7, 8, 8, 7, 9, 8), organized_satisfaction = c(9, 
9, 9, 10, 4, 4, 7, 7, 9, 7, 6, 8, 6, 9, 10, 10, 8, 8, 8, 7, 9, 
10, 7, 7, 9, 8, 10, 9, 8, 9, 9, 8, 7, 9, 6, 8, 7, 10, 10, 8, 
9, 7, 8, 8, 8, 9, 8, 6, 9, 8, 10, 7), cleanliness_satisfaction = c(10, 
8, 10, 10, 3, 10, 8, 8, 10, 8, 6, 9, 6, 10, 10, 10, 10, 8, 10, 
10, 9, 10, 8, 9, 8, 8, 10, 10, 7, 10, 10, 10, 10, 9, 10, 9, 10, 
10, 9, 10, 10, 6, 8, 8, 8, 7, 8, 7, 8, 10, 10, 10), staff_satisfaction = c(9, 
8, 8, 10, 1, 5, 6, 6, 10, 8, 7, 7, 4, 8, 10, 10, 9, 7, 10, 10, 
7, 10, 8, 7, 7, 8, 10, 10, 7, 9, 10, 7, 8, 9, 3, 7, 10, 10, 6, 
9, 10, 5, 8, 7, 8, 8, 6, 8, 9, 7, 10, 7), overall_experience = c(9, 
7, 9, 10, 3, 5, 7, 7, 10, 8, 7, 8, 4, 9, 9, 10, 9, 8, 9, 10, 
9, 10, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9, 10, 8, 6, 9, 9, 8, 9, 7, 7, 9, 10, 8, 7, 
9, 5, 8, 8, 7, 9, 7, 7, 8, 8, 10, 8), overall_quality = c(8, 
7, 9, 10, 5, 4, 8, 7, 10, 8, 7, 8, 4, 9, 9, 10, 10, 8, 9, 10, 
8, 10, 8, 7, 7, 8, 9, 10, 7, 4, 9, 9, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 10, 9, 8, 
10, 7, 9, 9, 7, 8, 7, 8, 8, 8, 9, 8), price_products = c(8, 7, 
8, 10, 2, 6, 7, 6, 9, 7, 7, 6, 6, 10, 7, 10, 6, 8, 9, 10, 7, 
10, 6, 4, 8, 7, 10, 9, 7, 6, 9, 8, 7, 7, 5, 9, 9, 8, 10, 7, 8, 
8, 8, 6, 7, 9, 7, 7, 9, 8, 10, 6), deals_savings = c(8, 8, 9, 
10, 5, 6, 9, 8, 10, 7, 6, 8, 6, 10, 9, 10, 9, 8, 10, 10, 6, 10, 
7, 6, 8, 7, 9, 10, 7, 6, 10, 8, 9, 8, 3, 9, 10, 10, 8, 8, 8, 
8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 6, 6, 8, 9, 10, 7), time_find_products = c(6, 
8, 9, 5, 2, 7.85106382978723, 9, 6, 10, 8, 6, 8, 6, 10, 7.85106382978723, 
10, 8, 7, 10, 10, 9, 10, 6, 6, 8, 8, 9, 10, 7, 6, 7.85106382978723, 
9, 8, 8, 9, 7.85106382978723, 7, 9, 9, 8, 10, 7, 8, 7, 7, 7, 
7, 7.85106382978723, 9, 7, 10, 6), overall_costs = c(8, 7, 9, 
10, 4, 5, 8, 7, 9, 7, 7, 8, 6, 10, 9, 10, 8, 8, 9, 10, 7, 10, 
7, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10, 7, 6, 9, 8, 8, 8, 8, 7, 8, 9, 8, 7, 9, 8, 
8, 7, 8, 8, 6, 7, 8, 8, 10, 7), wwpf = c(8, 7, 9, 9, 4, 4, 8, 
7, 9, 8, 6, 8, 6, 9, 8, 10, 8, 7, 9, 9, 7, 10, 8, 6, 7, 8, 8, 
10, 7, 4, 9, 9, 8, 8, 9, 8, 9, 9, 9, 7, 9, 8, 8, 8, 7, 8, 7, 
8, 9, 9, 10, 7), likelihood_return_3_months = c(8, 8, 10, 10, 
2, 2, 8, 7, 9, 8, 7, 9, 5, 10, 9, 10, 10, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 
8, 6, 8, 8, 8, 10, 8, 1, 9, 8, 9, 7, 8, 7, 8, 10, 8, 7, 10, 7, 
8, 8, 7, 8, 6, 6, 10, 9, 10, 9), nps = c(5, 7, 9, 10, 2, 2, 8, 
7, 9, 9, 6, 9, 4, 10, 9, 10, 10, 6, 9, 10, 9, 10, 7, 7, 8, 8, 
9, 10, 8, 0, 9, 6, 9, 8, 4, 8, 5, 10, 9, 8, 10, 6, 8, 8, 7, 8, 
6, 6, 10, 8, 10, 8), gender = c("m", "f", "m", "f", "m", "m", 
"m", "f", "f", "m", "f", "m", "f", "m", "m", "m", "f", "f", "m", 
"f", "m", "f", "m", "m", "m", "f", "f", "m", "m", "m", "f", "f", 
"m", "m", "f", "f", "f", "f", "f", "m", "m", "f", "f", "m", "m", 
"f", "m", "f", "f", "f", "m", "f"), education = c("hs", "college", 
"above_college", "hs", "hs", "above_college", "above_college", 
"above_college", "college", "college", "college", "above_college", 
"hs", "hs", "hs", "college", "above_college", "hs", "hs", "above_college", 
"above_college", "above_college", "college", "college", "college", 
"above_college", "hs", "college", "college", "above_college", 
"hs", "hs", "above_college", "above_college", "hs", "above_college", 
"above_college", "above_college", "college", "college", "college", 
"above_college", "hs", "college", "college", "above_college", 
"hs", "hs", "above_college", "above_college", "hs", "hs")), row.names = c(NA, 
-52L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: I am confused about your expected output do you need the one I answered below or `mtcars %>% map(~prop.table(table(.))) ` ?

Comment: Yes I need (mtcars %>% map(~prop.table(table(.)))) something like this but in form of dataframe. when I add %>% do.call(rbind,.) to above I think I lose some values. Case closed

In addition, need advice incase there were 2 categorical variable if like species in iris then how would I dynimically get values (I hope this clarifies a bit (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57423120/build-a-function-which-gives-table-of-distribution-percentage-of-variable-dynami))

Comment: but `mtcars %>% map(~prop.table(table(.)))` gives list of different length. How will you bind it into one dataframe? better to update your post with exact expected output.

Comment: I want to fill no matched with 0 but not lose any values, I read somewhere rbindlist(fill=TRUE) something like that helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not really sure what you want, but perhaps this code returns it.

```
mtcars %>%
  imap(~ {
    prop_table <- .x %>% 
      table() %>% 
      prop.table()

    temp <- cbind(matrix(c(.y, "prop", "--"), ncol = 1),
                  rbind(names(prop_table), c(prop_table), "--")) 
    colnames(temp) <- NULL
    as_tibble(temp)
  }) %>% 
  do.call("bind_rows", .)
```

[Edited]
Well, how is this ?

```
mtcars %>% 
  imap(~ .x %>% 
         table() %>% 
         prop.table() %>% 
         as_tibble() %>% 
         set_names("value", .y)) %>% 
  reduce(full_join) %>% 
  arrange(as.numeric(value)) %>% 
  t() %>% 
  as_tibble(rownames = "-") %>% 
  set_names(unlist(.[1,])) %>% 
  slice(-1)
```

[Edited 2]
Your `temp` isn't `data.frame` but `list`. You need to use `map(~ map(.x, ~))`.

```
temp <- split(df1, df1$gender) 
temp %>% 
  map_dfr(~ 
            imap(.x, ~ .x %>% 
                   table() %>% 
                   prop.table() %>% 
                   as_tibble() %>% 
                   set_names("value", .y)) %>% 
            reduce(full_join) %>% 
            arrange(as.numeric(value)) %>% 
            base::t() %>% 
            as_tibble(rownames = "-") %>% 
            set_names(unlist(.[1,])) %>% 
            slice(-1)
          )
```

Comment: Thank you @cuttlefish44, I want the same thing which you have posted above, I just want to convert the values sent by you to be part of header (For ex: my dataset has values between 1-10, I just gave an example of mtcars ). 
Output would look like 

(Header row)Variable   4 6 8 10.4 10.3 .....
(First row) mpg         0 0  0  2.4 3.7

Comment: Now I think maybe mtcars was not a good example to replicate the problem at hand because my numeric variable are integer in range (1 to 10) for all numeric columns

Comment: OK, I edited (If it isn't what you want, please show me your data and the correct output you want, reproduced by the data).

Comment: Thank you Cfish, You are amazing at R & understanding at same time. 
I edited & added image to explain last bit. Please checks edit in my question

Comment: I edited my answer. Uh, the image URL is correct ? I can't open it.

Comment: Actually adding map_dir code doesnt work correctly on list as intended. But I marked the answer.